# How do i modify entities created in google datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've created some entities in google datastore to go for an sqlless solution for my database. How can i connect to the datastore using php and modify the entities that i have created?

I am using google app engine to host my application. By extension I cant find any documentation as to how I can query the datastore and modify its values once i have connected.

Answer (score 1):

For you to install the Client Library for Cloud Datastore on your PHP, you need to run the following command:

```
composer require google/cloud-datastore
```

Besides that, you can get all the information from how to configure it on this official documentation: [Datastore mode Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php).

An example of a query, is the following one.

```
$query = $datastore->query()
    ->kind('Task')
    ->filter('done', '=', false)
    ->filter('priority', '>=', 4)
    ->order('priority', Query::ORDER_DESCENDING);
```

After that, you need to execute it as following: `$result = $datastore->runQuery($query);`.

This is a sample example - that I took from [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#query_interface) - of issuing a query against a Datastore mode database. It retrieves all tasks that are not yet done with priorities greater than or equal to 4, sorted in descending order by priority.

Another example, this one of updating a value from the database is the following.

```
$transaction = $datastore->transaction();
$key = $datastore->key('Task', 'sampleTask');
$task = $transaction->lookup($key);
$task['priority'] = 5;
$transaction->update($task);
$transaction->commit();
```

On this example, you are updating a simple entity `Task`, setting it's `priority` to `5`.

I would recommend you to access these following two articles, that give you more examples and usages of queries to read, update, delete, etc., values from your database.

- [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries)
- [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities)

In addition, you can check the official repository from the API using the below link.

- [Google Cloud PHP Datastore](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-datastore)

Let me know if the information helped you!